# How to list columns using COPY command with Redshift?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, create-table

I am trying to load a table using the `COPY` command and specifying the **Column list** as per the redshift documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html#copy-column-mapping-jsonpaths.

The file content of s3://mybucket/data/listing/data.csv is header followed by the file content. File content below:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4. c5, c6, c7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
11,11,11,11,11,11,11
21,21,21,21,21,21,21
31,31,31,31,31,31,31
.........................
.........................
.........................
```

And I am using the following command to load the `listing` table which only has three columns c1, c2, c3.

```
copy listing(c1, c2, c3)
from 's3://mybucket/data/listing/data.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
CSV
```

However, Redshift is not allowing the copy and failing with the following error:

```
1202    Extra column(s) found
```

Why is it? I am specifying the selected columns with the same name.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently limit the columns in a `COPY` statement this way. You can either load all columns to a temporary table and then `INSERT` them into your target table or you can define the file(s) to be loaded as an external table and then `INSERT` directly to your target using `SELECT` from the external table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html