# Load CSVs into Redshift table, where some CSVs lack some columns

Tags: python, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

## Goal

Load all data from CSV files in an S3 bucket into a Redshift table.

## Problem

Some files lack a subset of columns.

## Example

In the real world, my bucket gets new CSVs daily, but consider this simpler example.

Suppose I have a `fruit` table:

| id | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INTEGER | VARCHAR | VARCHAR | INTEGER |

Suppose I have 2 CSVs.

`test1.csv`:

| id | name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | abc | 123 |
| 2 | orange | def | 456 |

`test2.csv`:

| id | name | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | banana | 421 |
| 4 | pear | 68 |

Note that `test2.csv` lacks the `val1` column.

## Question

Is there any way to load arbitrarily many CSVs into a Redshift table, where some files may lack any subset of (non-primary key) columns, using built-in Redshift functionality and SQL? Will some other AWS service(s) get the job done? Or must I turn to Python at this point? Is this a job for psycopg2 and/or SQLAlchemy?

## What I've read

I'd use `COPY`, but the docs seem to say it doesn't support my scenario. A [column list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html#copy-column-list) must match the order of column names in the source data, but if *any* columns can be missing, then that order isn't constant, so I believe this functionality can't help me. The missing columns aren't always at the end of the dataset, so I believe `COPY`'s [`FILLRECORD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-fillrecord) parameter won't help me.

The idea of [creating a temporary or external table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218207/8605348) is interesting, but I'm unsure if it supports my scenario. Wouldn't I just run into the same issues?

## Update: Solutions I found

The simplest solution using AWS is AppFlow. I confirmed that it will load data from CSV even if columns defined in the destination table are missing from a source file. I set the default values to `NULL` when creating the table in Redshift.

If one wants to do something more complicated with AWS Glue and Python, then I confirmed Pandas or SQLAlchemy will load CSVs with missing columns. AWS Data Wrangler should also do it, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: You would need to modify the COPY command for each file depending on which columns are present. The column list should be able to handle a situation where not all columns are provided. They would be set to their default value. See: [Loading default column values - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading_default_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you start looking for python-based stream processing options:

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

def get_s3_file_descriptors():
    raise NotImplementedError


def get_superset_of_columns():
    # building a superset of columns, reading just first rows
    columns = {}
    for f in get_s3_file_descriptors():
        for column in Table.from_csv(f, header=True).columns:
            columns[column] = None
    return columns


def get_rows():
    columns = get_superset_of_columns()
    for f in get_s3_file_descriptors():
        table = Table.from_csv(f, header=True)
        current_columns = set(table.columns)
        for column in columns:
            if column not in current_columns:
                table.update(column=None)
        yield from table.take(*columns).into_iter_rows(tuple)


get_rows()
```

Comment: I'd just use `pandas.DataFrame.-to_sql()`.

Comment: @ardaar sure! whichever option suits you.
the option I shared is about streaming them (no matter how big files are).
Pandas based solution will require all files to fit into memory.

Comment: Good to know and that's probably best. +1. Thank you.